# Predicate<Bool>, pointless or useful?

Tags: c#, boolean, predicate

I'm trying to get my head around the `Predicate<T>` type and I can understand it when T is anything, except for bool.  If you have `Predicate<bool>`, I don't see how that can be used.

Can someone tell me if this is a silly thing to do or if it actually serves a purpose?

`Predicate<T>` already returns a bool, so then testing a condition on a bool seems a bit pointless... or have I got it wrong?

Comment: If you think it's useless, don't use it. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Aaron: I'm asking cause I want to know if it actually has any uses, as I cannot think of any...

Comment: Why does it need any uses? Would it even make sense to define it as `Predicate<T not Boolean>`?

Comment: @Anon: As you can see from the answers, in some (not many cases) it does make sense to use it.  I'm not sure what you're getting at?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Predicate means a function that takes a T (any type) and returns a bool.

```
Predicate<int> isEven = i => i % 2 == 0;
```

You're mostly right. For bool, there's not many uses that come to mind. I mean, there's only so much you can do with a bool.

```
Predicate<bool> isFalse = input => !input;
Predicate<bool> isTrue = input => input;
```

You might use it like this:

```
var listOfBools = new List<Bool>() { true, false, false, true, true };
var trues = listOfBools.FindAll(isTrue);
var falses = listOfBools.FindAll(isFalse);
```

It's certainly less useful, simply because there's only so many things you can do with a bool.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just because you have a bool already doesn't mean that you want to return exactly that bool. For instance i can imagine the IsFalse predicate that returns true if the argument is false.